# When building GCC on Alpine without root user, I am getting an error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

Tags: linux, gcc, build, alpine-linux

I am trying to build GCC on Alpine Linux. I do not have root access or sudo enabled user. I am following [GCC Wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC). I got this output.

```
~/objdir $ $PWD/../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-5.2.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libcilkrts support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for libvtv support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/asgeek/objdir':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I have searched through the internet for couple of days but couldn't find proper solution. Please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you can adjust your running environment's PATH variable and add the directory where the compiler is so the configure process can find it. Every user can modify PATH on the session they are working on.

Comment: @Edmundo I do not have already installed C compiler to add to the PATH variable.

Comment: Sounds like a catch 22. I guess you need some other C compiler so that you can then build gcc.

Comment: @Edmundo do you know a way to install other C compiler without root or sudo user?

Comment: ? Isn't the default "user" `root` in Alpine Linux ? ... The install tool is `apk`. Please do `apk | less` to figure out how to install the require gcc and g++, etc. ( You will also need mpfr, gmp to build an extra gcc.) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux

Comment: Yes I know. But what I want is to create a script to build GCC for non-root environment. So I need to everything with non-root user.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same error while installing python in alpine, I fixed it with this:

```
apk --update add gcc make g++ zlib-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

> But what I want is to create a script to build GCC for non-root
>   environment

Well, then create a user (May be you already did), and install {gcc, g++, etc. build requirements} with `apk` , and do the build in `/home/[name]/gcc-build/` with

```
1) ../gcc-5.4.0/configure --prefix=/home/[name]/gcc54 --program-suffix=54 --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
2) make
```

GCC version 5 or lower is suggested. Note : If e.g. gcc-4.9.x, the configuring command, etc. is different.

Comment: »» no privilege to use `apk` command «« : Well, then I'd suggest setting up a similar 'Alpine Linux' somewhere. Install gcc build requirements. Build gcc in /home/same-name/, and make it a .tar package. Then unpack new-gcc.tar to your current OS : /home/same-name/ . (Note : Alpine is a 78MB live CD.)

Comment: Yes, that is the only option I also ended up with. As I got to know by searching all over the internet, it must be installed all the build essentials on alpine linux (or any OS) before we compile/build anything on it. Without having root access or sudo, we will not be able to make the OS a build environment. That's where I stuck at. Thank you for the support. If there is any other method to do this. Please let me know.